# How to get tilt line between two tabs in Android

Tags: android, layout, drawable, facebook-messenger, divider

[image: example]

I want to get tabs just like the one shown in Image, The problem is the tilt line, I have already tried the code for left and right drawable as follows:

right.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/blueJiffy"/>
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/dph5"
    android:topRightRadius="@dimen/dph5" />
</shape>
```

left.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/blueJiffy"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/dph5"
    android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/dph5" />
</shape>
```

using this I have achieved the effect:

[image: this]

I also want to color the clicked tab blue and previous tab should be colored white

Please note that these tabs are already available in facebook messenger android application.

Comment: i don't believe you can achieve this through xml

Comment: So, How can we achieve this,
May be use custom drawable java class ?

Comment: custom images, each one should have selected and normal state which cross each other

Comment: or custom drawable

Comment: I understood the Custom Images part but I want to use Custom Drawable to achieve this, Can you help me with Custom Drawable Code? As I am new in android.

Comment: it will be little hard for new devs, and i prefer to use images